# Apache Jackrabbit. Session.importXML() and Observation

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I am using the import feature of Apache Jackrabbit for importing System view XML.

```
session.importXML(parentNode.getPath(),inputStream,ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_THROW);
```

A new node is being created with the contents of XML, before importing I registered an event listener just to get access to the new created node an do some post-import actions, I registered my listener that way:

```
EventListener afterImportListener = new EventListener() {...}
observationManager.addEventListener(afterImportListener, Event.NODE_ADDED,stageNode.getPath(),true,null,null,false);
```

No event is being dispatched to my EventListener.  Does Observation work with importXML? is there any other way to get access to the new created node/s after importing?

Comment: `importXML` and observation are both standard JCR features, so it may be possible to determine what the behaviour should be by reading the spec. If Jackrabbit is not behaving accordingly, that's a bug, which i imagine its developers would be pleased to hear about.

Comment: spec's chapter 11 about importing doesn't say anything about importXML.  spec's chapter 12 says:   "The scope of event reporting is implementation-dependent. [...] For example, on an import, move or remove of a subgraph containing a large number of items, "  What's Jackrabbit case?  Does Jackrabbit support event notification on import?

Comment: Ah, okay. The JCR spec contains a depressing number of holes where behaviour is implementation-dependent. I'm afraid i can't answer your question. However, in my experience, the Jackrabbit mailing list is rather good, and i would suggest you ask this question (or post a link to this question) there if you don't get an answer here soon.

Comment: There is a (sparse) [wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/JcrSpecImplementation) on what implementation choices jackrabbit makes. If you get an answer, feel free to add it there!